# Remove Canvas(s) in Python 3.5

Tags: python, canvas

I am a newbie to Python and now try to self-learn the code by modifying the ttkcalendar module. Basically, my goal is to base on the module to produce a calendar schedule which allows to show specific dates with event. Hence, I create a txt records to store the data and read them when the calendar is loaded. Based on the data, I highlight the dates by creating a number of canvas on the calendar (by procedure: def _show_selection(self, text, bbox)). Now the problem is the system does not help me to remove the previous canvas when moving on to another month by clicking "prev" or "next" button. As the code being modified, the original place_forget() syntax seems not working anymore. I think my problems are two parts:

1. any method to help me point to the full reference to the canvas created? I don't even know their full reference!
2. any method to remove/delete/destroy the canvas so I can start over the highlighting task when moving to another month?

My code is attached as below, many many thanks for your help. ^.^

```
"""
Simple calendar using ttk Treeview together with calendar and datetime
classes.
"""
import calendar
from calendar import monthrange
import tkinter
import tkinter.font
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import time
from datetime import date


def get_calendar(locale, fwday):
    # instantiate proper calendar class
    if locale is None:
        return calendar.TextCalendar(fwday)
    else:
        return calendar.LocaleTextCalendar(fwday, locale)

class Calendar(ttk.Frame):
    # XXX ToDo: cget and configure

    datetime = calendar.datetime.datetime
    timedelta = calendar.datetime.timedelta

    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        """
        WIDGET-SPECIFIC OPTIONS

            locale, firstweekday, year, month, selectbackground,
            selectforeground
        """
        # remove custom options from kw before initializating ttk.Frame
        fwday = kw.pop('firstweekday', calendar.MONDAY)
        year = kw.pop('year', self.datetime.now().year)
        month = kw.pop('month', self.datetime.now().month)
        locale = kw.pop('locale', None)
        sel_bg = kw.pop('selectbackground', '#ecffc4')
        sel_fg = kw.pop('selectforeground', '#05640e')

        self._date = self.datetime(year, month, 1)
        self._selection = None # no date selected

        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kw)

        self._cal = get_calendar(locale, fwday)

        self.__setup_styles()       # creates custom styles
        self.__place_widgets()      # pack/grid used widgets
        self.__config_calendar()    # adjust calendar columns and setup tags
        # configure a canvas, and proper bindings, for selecting dates
        self.__setup_selection(sel_bg, sel_fg)

        # store items ids, used for insertion later
        self._items = [self._calendar.insert('', 'end', values='')
                            for _ in range(6)]
        # insert dates in the currently empty calendar
        self._build_calendar()

        # set the minimal size for the widget
        # self._calendar.bind('<Map>', self.__minsize)


    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
           if item in ('year', 'month'):
               raise AttributeError("attribute '%s' is not writeable" % item)
           elif item == 'selectbackground':
               self._canvas['background'] = value
           elif item == 'selectforeground':
               self._canvas.itemconfigure(self._canvas.text, item=value)
           else:
               ttk.Frame.__setitem__(self, item, value)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item in ('year', 'month'):
            return getattr(self._date, item)
        elif item == 'selectbackground':
            return self._canvas['background']
        elif item == 'selectforeground':
            return self._canvas.itemcget(self._canvas.text, 'fill')
        else:
            r = ttk.tclobjs_to_py({item: ttk.Frame.__getitem__(self, item)})
            return r[item]

    def __setup_styles(self):
        # custom ttk styles
        style = ttk.Style(self.master)
        arrow_layout = lambda dir: (
            [('Button.focus', {'children': [('Button.%sarrow' % dir, None)]})]
        )
        style.layout('L.TButton', arrow_layout('left'))
        style.layout('R.TButton', arrow_layout('right'))        

    def __place_widgets(self):
        # header frame and its widgets
        hframe = ttk.Frame(self)
        lbtn = ttk.Button(hframe, style='L.TButton', command=self._prev_month)
        rbtn = ttk.Button(hframe, style='R.TButton', command=self._next_month)
        self._header = ttk.Label(hframe, width=15, anchor='center')
        # the calendar
        #self._calendar = ttk.Treeview(show='', selectmode='none', height=7)
        self._calendar = ttk.Treeview(self, show='', selectmode='none', height=7)

        # pack the widgets
        hframe.pack(in_=self, side='top', pady=4, anchor='center')
        lbtn.grid(in_=hframe)
        self._header.grid(in_=hframe, column=1, row=0, padx=12)
        rbtn.grid(in_=hframe, column=2, row=0)
        self._calendar.pack(in_=self, expand=1, fill='both', side='bottom')

    def __config_calendar(self):
        cols = self._cal.formatweekheader(3).split()
        self._calendar['columns'] = cols
        self._calendar.tag_configure('header', background='grey90')
        self._calendar.insert('', 'end', values=cols, tag='header')
        # adjust its columns width
        font = tkinter.font.Font()
        maxwidth = max(font.measure(col) for col in cols)
        for col in cols:
            self._calendar.column(col, width=maxwidth, minwidth=maxwidth,
                anchor='e')

    def __setup_selection(self, sel_bg, sel_fg):

        self._font = tkinter.font.Font()
        self._canvas = canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self._calendar,
            background=sel_bg, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        canvas.text = canvas.create_text(0, 0, fill=sel_fg, anchor='w')

        canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda evt: canvas.place_forget())
        self._calendar.bind('<Configure>', lambda evt: canvas.place_forget())
        self._calendar.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self._pressed)

    #def __minsize(self, evt):
    #    width, height = self._calendar.master.geometry().split('x')
    #    height = height[:height.index('+')]
    #    self._calendar.master.minsize(width, height)

    def _build_calendar(self):
        year, month = self._date.year, self._date.month

        # update header text (Month, YEAR)
        header = self._cal.formatmonthname(year, month, 0)
        self._header['text'] = header.title()

        # update calendar shown dates
        cal = self._cal.monthdayscalendar(year, month)

        for indx, item in enumerate(self._items):
            week = cal[indx] if indx < len(cal) else []
            fmt_week = [('%01d' % day) if day else '' for day in week]
            self._calendar.item(item, values=fmt_week)


    def _show_selection(self, text, bbox):
        """Configure canvas for a new selection."""
        x, y, width, height = bbox
        textw = self._font.measure(text)

#        canvas = self._canvas

        if int(text) == date.today().day:
            canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self._calendar, width = 200, height = 100,
                background="#ecffc4", borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
            canvas.text = canvas.create_text(0, 0, fill="#05640e", anchor='w',)
        else:
            canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self._calendar, width = 200, height = 100,
                background="#FFE0E0", borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
            canvas.text = canvas.create_text(0, 0, fill="#FF0000", anchor='w',)

        canvas.configure(width=width, height=height)
        canvas.coords(canvas.text, width - textw, height / 2 - 1)
        canvas.itemconfigure(canvas.text, text=text)
        canvas.place(in_=self._calendar, x=x, y=y)

#        canvas.configure(width=width, height=height)
#        canvas.coords(canvas.text, width - textw, height / 2 - 1)
#        canvas.itemconfigure(canvas.text, text=text)
#        canvas.place(in_=self._calendar, x=x, y=y)


    def _show_daybox(self, in_text):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        daybox_frm = ttk.Frame(self.root)
        daybox_frm.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
        daybox_label = ttk.Label(daybox_frm, text = in_text)
        daybox_label.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W, fill=X, expand=YES)
        daybox_button = ttk.Button(daybox_frm, text='Ok')
        daybox_button.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W, fill=X, expand=YES)

    # Callbacks

    def _pressed(self, evt):

        """Clicked somewhere in the calendar."""
        x, y, widget = evt.x, evt.y, evt.widget
        item = widget.identify_row(y)
        column = widget.identify_column(x)

        if not column or not item in self._items:
            # clicked in the weekdays row or just outside the columns
            return

        item_values = widget.item(item)['values']
        if not len(item_values): # row is empty for this month
            return

        text = item_values[int(column[1]) - 1]
        if not text: # date is empty
            return

        bbox = widget.bbox(item, column)
        if not bbox: # calendar not visible yet
            return

        # update and then show selection
        text = '%01d' % text
#        self._selection = (text, item, column)
        self._show_selection(text, bbox)
#        self._show_daybox(str(self._date.year) + "-" + str(self._date.month) + "-" + text)

    def _prev_month(self):
        """Updated calendar to show the previous month."""
        self._canvas.place_forget()

        self._date = self._date - self.timedelta(days=1)
        self._date = self.datetime(self._date.year, self._date.month, 1)
        self._build_calendar() # reconstuct calendar

    def _next_month(self):
        """Update calendar to show the next month."""
        self._canvas.place_forget()

        year, month = self._date.year, self._date.month
        self._date = self._date + self.timedelta(
            days=calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1] + 1)
        self._date = self.datetime(self._date.year, self._date.month, 1)
        self._build_calendar() # reconstruct calendar


    def set_day(self, day):
        w = self._calendar
        if not w.winfo_viewable():
            w.after(200, self.set_day, day)
            return

        text = '%01d' % day
        column = None
        for iid in self._items:
            rowvals = w.item(iid, 'values')
            try:
                column = rowvals.index(text)
            except ValueError as err:
                pass
            else:
                item = iid
                bbox = w.bbox(iid, column)
                break

        if column is not None:
            self._selection = (text, item, column)
            self._show_selection(text, bbox)             

    # Properties

    @property
    def selection(self):
        """Return a datetime representing the current selected date."""
        if not self._selection:
            return None

        year, month = self._date.year, self._date.month
        return self.datetime(year, month, int(self._selection[0]))

def test():
    import sys
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title('Ttk Calendar')
    ttkcal = Calendar(firstweekday=calendar.SUNDAY)
    ttkcal.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

    if 'win' not in sys.platform:
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.theme_use('clam')

    # import the selected dates from records

    (_ , cur_month) = monthrange(date.today().year , date.today().month)
    for j in range(0 , CalRds.__len__()):
        Rd_date, Rd_name = CalRds[j].split(',')    
        Rd_yr, Rd_mth, Rd_day = Rd_date.split('-')    
        if (int(Rd_yr) == ttkcal._date.year) and (int(Rd_mth) == ttkcal._date.month):
            for k in range (0, cur_month + 1):
                if int(Rd_day) == k:
                    ttkcal.set_day(k)
                    break

    ttkcal.set_day(date.today().day[enter image description here][1]) #    
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    """Reading the records file"""

    in_f = open('CalRds.txt', 'r+')
    CalRds = in_f.read().split("\n")    
    ## 0 for date
    ## 1 for Name


    """Loading the calendar"""
    test()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't neccessarily have to delete the canvas. Just create another canvas and grid it on the previous one, with the the same dimensions and on the same row and column.